# Probability problem possibly based on principle of inclusion exclusion

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

The problem reads as follows:

> Probabilities that Rajesh passes in Physics, Math and Chemistry are $p$, $m$ and $c$ respectively. Of these subjects, Rajesh has $75%$ chance of passing in at least one, $50%$ chance of passing in at least two and $40%$ chance of passing in exactly two. Find which of the following is true:
>
> (a) $p+m+c=\frac{19}{20}$
> (b) $p+m+c=\frac{27}{20}$
> (c) $pmc = \frac{1}{20}$
> (d) $pmc = \frac{1}{8}$

Given answer is (b)

What all I am able to guess, is following

Given:

1. At least one = $75\%$
2. At least two = $50\%$
3. Exactly two = $40\%$

From this

4. Exactly three = At least two - Exactly two $= 50\%-40\% = 10\%$
5. Exactly one = At least one - At least two $= 75\% - 50\% = 25\%$
6. None = $100\%$ - At least one $=100\%-75\%=25\%$

However I dont find how to proceed.

Comment: is there a reason we change from mpc to pmc? - it makes reading the question difficult

Comment: you mean in question it is specified in order m , p and c and in options it is given in order p, m and c? If yes, then no specific reason. Also sum and multiplication are commutative operations.

Comment: I fail to understand how answer can be 27/20, i.e. > 1

Comment: @trueblueanil; the probabilities aren't like that : p=0.7, m=0.8, c=0.5 for example

Comment: exactly 3 tells us pmc=1/10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw a Venn diagram, you will find that

$p+m+c =$ P(exactly one) + 2P(exactly two) + 3P(exactly three)

= $\dfrac{25 + 2\cdot40 + 3\cdot10}{100} = \dfrac{135}{100} = \dfrac{27}{20}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can see the following, possibly from a Venn diagram.

$p+m+c=P(\text{exactly one passed})+2\cdot P(\text{exactly two passed})+3\cdot P(\text{all three passed})$

Comment: yep yep, is there any other more formal equation like way that communicate the same. From Venn diagram sounds a bit informal proof.

Comment: @Mahesha999 I might try something along the lines of: In adding $p+m+c$, the double overlap is counted twice since it is in two of the sets, and similarly the triple overlap is counted three times.

Comment: Yes I get that, and I guess this is what is depicted by the equation you gave in the answer, but is there any other way to interpret the solution, because in probability there are multiple ways to solve single problem (though I guess this might not be the case with this particular problem)